# I have Unit Test with more than one class but crash

Tags: qt, unit-testing

I have a 4 class test unit
I'm in the main doing the following:

```
#include <QtTest>
#include "CategoryTests.cpp"
#include "SerializationTests.cpp"
#include "TaskTests.cpp"
#include "TestTests.cpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int status = 0;
   {
       CategoryTests tc;
       status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
   }
   {
       SerializationTests tc;
       status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
   }
   {
       TaskTests tc;
       status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
   }
   {
       TestTests tc;
       status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
   }
   return status;
}
```

But for some reason, the crib pops up and I can not understand why. I ask for your help

[image]

Comment: Did you debug and figure out at which line it's crashing?

Comment: @user1055395 No. I could not. it's after I wrote the main start of cracking I could not ignore the normal debug

Comment: The question is obviously about the code that tests something and without that something we cannot know. There must be std::vector::erase called in the test and not in main().